# The best process to access osm data

Tags: android, openstreetmap

i want to use the server of openstreetmap ,i have found a lot of solution but,always , there are limit, so for example mapquest has just 15000 request per day and it's not possible to use it without connexion and overpass api offer just 10000 request by day,i want to make apps in android for search POI,i want to choose the good  way for futur use to do the search, i don't know if there another solution,please help me, and thank you for advanced.

Comment: If 10000 request by day are not enough for your then [install your own Overpass API instance](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Installation). Nothing comes for free.

Comment: yes,Thank you very much for your answer.